# Dictionary(Of String, String) Cannot Evaluate Expression

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dictionary, webforms

When calling a Sub to populate a System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary with keys and values from a DictionaryEntry(), upon examining the Dictionary in Debug mode every property has a red circle with an X and contains the text "Unable to evaluate expression."  It appears to be working, it will even complain if I try to add two entries with the same Key/Value pair. No keys or values are present either, even though my test string (valuesString) is populated.

I am calling the Sub from the ItemInserted event of a FormView (.Net Framework 4, Visual Studio 2013 Webforms Application)

```
Protected Sub PopulateDictionary(myValues As DictionaryEntry())

        Dim de As DictionaryEntry
        Dim valuesString As String = String.Empty
        Dim myDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        For Each de In myValues

            'This works - the string is populated with key/value pairs
            valuesString &= "Key=" & de.Key.ToString() & ", " & _
              "Value=" & de.Value.ToString() & "<br/>"

            'This doesn't - just get the red circle with an X
            myDictionary.Add(de.Key.ToString(), de.Value.ToString())

        Next
End Sub
```

What is going on here? I have restarted Visual Studio with no luck.

Comment: I did solve this by passing in the Parameters collection from SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs instead.  I'm still not sure why the Dictionary fails to work within the ItemInserted event so I'm hoping maybe someone has an answer about that.

Answer (score 0):

odd that this works with the `"<br/>"`. it looks like it's missing the closing quote. (and maybe ToString() is not needed?)

```
valuesString &= "Key=" & de.Key.ToString() & ", " & _
          "Value=" & de.Value.ToString() & "<br/>"
```

it looks like this:

```
myDictionary.Add(de.Key.ToString(), de.Value.ToString())
```

just needs to be:

```
myDictionary.Add(valuesString)
```

or (not sure...):

```
myDictionary.Add(DictionaryEntry())
```